# What will happen to a Bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

What happen to a bounty if there is no answer till the close date of it. Actually I have set a bounty on the question [ [How to solve these two simultaneous "divisibilities" : $n+1\mid m^2+1$ and $m+1\mid n^2+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671427/how-to-solve-this-two-simultaneous-divisibilities-n1-mid-m21-and-m1-m) ] that have no answers it is going to be close in $2$ days I wanted to know that what will happen with this after $2$ days if there will be no answers

Comment: This seems to be rather [frequent question about bounties](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bounty?sort=frequent). See [What happens if my bounty time expires?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3144) or [What happens to the bounty I added to a questions if no new answers are provided before the bounty expires?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2321). The [tag-info for the bounty tag](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/bounty/info) contains also some links with useful information about bounties.

Comment: This is only tangentially related, but if you still have no answers after the bounty expires, you might be interested in my suggestion to collect somewhere unresolved bounties. For details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/23715) and [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/43020/2016/7/26).